# Neo4j Parent - Child : get all top level nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have a node collection like

```
M1 -> M2 -> M4 -> M5
M1 -> M3 
M6
M7 -> M8 
M7 -> M9
M7 -> M10
```

The Cypher Query should return me all top level nodes i.e M1, M6 & M7.

How to write that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need all nodes who don't have any incoming relationships

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)<--()
RETURN DISTINCT(n);
```